# I want to know how to perform the CRUD operation in GreenDAO?

Tags: android, mvp, greendao, greendao-generator

I am very new to GreenDAO, I don't know how to do CRUD operations in GreenDAO. I did some CRUD operation to retrieve the username and password that was totally making me confusion.Any one help to do CRUD operation in
GreenDAO.

Code:

```
loginDao=DataProvider.getLoginDao(context);
QueryBuilder PasswordQuery = loginDao.queryBuilder().where(LoginDao.Properties.Password.eq("@user123"));
```

output Logcat:

```
   name: de.greenrobot.dao.query.QueryBuilder@68ca4d0

(Like this I got error when i retrieved the username and password)
```

Anyone resolve my problem to make me understand of those issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is the Output of the toString() method of `QueryBuilder`

Comment: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/

Comment: i got confused how to retrieved the fields from green dao using string variable

Comment: I need some brief explanation  about this CRUD operation in Green DAO